# Problems compiling antiquated code using the epic and eepic packages

Tags: compiling, incompatibility

I was given an extremely large tex file I need to compile, but when trying to compile it, I repeatedly get a non-pdf special ignored error followed by the document without any of the figures included.

After some research, I have come to the conclusion that it must be the packages epic and eepic, but I am unable to figure out a workaround so that it will still compile properly without rewriting hundreds of lines of code.

Below is a typical example of what is causing me fits:

EDIT: Updated the sample code so that it can compile with all the errors I am experiencing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,amsfonts]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epic,eepic}
\begin{document}

\date{}

\begin{figure}[h] % This is Figure 1.1
\begin{picture}(440,480)(-230,-280)
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.3pt}
\drawline(-388,898)(564,-887)
\drawline(1200,77)(-1200,77)
\drawline(-36,-900)(-36,900)
\drawline(714,897)(-636,-903)
\drawline(1194,605)(-1191,-667)
\drawline(600,-899)(-747,897)
\drawline(388,-898)(-564,887)
\put(-660,-259){\circle{1248}}
\put(-20,-99){\circle{32}}
\put(-88,105){\circle{104}}
\put(-16,-63){\circle{40}}
\put(484,-363){\circle{1040}}
\put(-60,-91){\circle{48}}
\put(120,209){\circle{312}}
\put(-12,5){\circle{144}}
\put(-216,-63){\circle{280}}
\put(288,-175){\circle{504}}
\put(84,437){\circle{720}}
\end{picture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post and make the code fully compilable? It would help the solvers to start experimenting with your example.

Comment: @Malipivo I've updated the post, hopefully that is enough of a working example to get the idea. If I try to compile this, I run into the same problems I've tried to describe.

Comment: not related to the problem, but since `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, it's not necessary to load the latter explicitly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without changing anything in the code (I just modified 0.3pt into 0.2pt to make the picture fit in normal paper), using `pict2e` (that has `\Line` instead of `\drawline`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,amsfonts]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{epic,eepic}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\newcommand{\drawline}{\Line}
\begin{document}

\date{}

\begin{figure}[ht] % This is Figure 1.1
\begin{picture}(440,480)(-230,-280)
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.2pt}% 0.3 is too big
\drawline(-388,898)(564,-887)
\drawline(1200,77)(-1200,77)
\drawline(-36,-900)(-36,900)
\drawline(714,897)(-636,-903)
\drawline(1194,605)(-1191,-667)
\drawline(600,-899)(-747,897)
\drawline(388,-898)(-564,887)
\put(-660,-259){\circle{1248}}
\put(-20,-99){\circle{32}}
\put(-88,105){\circle{104}}
\put(-16,-63){\circle{40}}
\put(484,-363){\circle{1040}}
\put(-60,-91){\circle{48}}
\put(120,209){\circle{312}}
\put(-12,5){\circle{144}}
\put(-216,-63){\circle{280}}
\put(288,-175){\circle{504}}
\put(84,437){\circle{720}}
\end{picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I ran into a couple unforeseen errors in some other figures but I was able to repair everything and compile it with this example.